# Save foreach loop results onto an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I would like `$servico` to store all iterations of this `foreach ($produtos as $produto)` loop, into an array:

However, I'm getting the id, name and domain of the last occurrence only.

```
$servico = array();

        foreach ($resposta->products as $produtos)
        {


            foreach ($produtos as $produto)
            {

                if (!empty($produto->domain))
                {
                    $servico['id'] = $produto->id;
                    $servico['name'] = $produto->name;
                    $servico['domain'] = $produto->domain;

                    //seta o pid do produto
                    $servicoVo->setPid($produto->pid);

                    //vai buscar o gid do produto:
                    $groupId = $servicoDao->grupoServico($servicoVo);

                    //adiciona o group id ao array
                    $servico['gid'] = $groupId;
                }
            }
        }


        //devolve o array
        if (!empty($servico)) 
        {
            //echo '<pre>';
            //var_dump($servico);
            //echo '</pre>';
            return $servico;
        }
```

Can I have a little help here? :D

Thanks,
MEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rewriting the id, name, and domain keys each time. Do this instead, after of course generating `$groupID`:

```
$servicio[] = array('id'     => $produto->id
                   ,'name'   => $produto->name
                   ,'domain' => $produto->domain
                   ,'gid'    => $groupId);
```

This creates a new entry in the array, filling it with the new stuff you want. Functionally identical to the other examples of creating a temporary array, without having to actually create a temporary array.

Answer (score 0):

You keep changing elements of `$servico` not adding elements on to it. Try doing something like this:

```
$newItem = Array(); // create the new item we want to add to $servico

// ...populate it like you have been...
$newItem ['id'] = $produto->id;
$newItem ['name'] = $produto->name;
$newItem ['domain'] = $produto->domain;

//seta o pid do produto
$servicoVo->setPid($produto->pid);

//vai buscar o gid do produto:
$groupId = $servicoDao->grupoServico($servicoVo);

//adiciona o group id ao array
$newItem ['gid'] = $groupId;

$servico[] = $newItem; // <-- note this change here, we add the new item to the array
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your script to store all iterations and not just the last one, you'll want to modify your script's foreach nested loop to do something similar to this:

```
foreach ($resposta->products as $produtos)
{
    foreach ($produtos as $produto)
    {

        if (!empty($produto->domain))
        {
            // Create a temporary array
            $newServico = array();

            $newServico['id'] = $produto->id;
            $newServico['name'] = $produto->name;
            $newServico['domain'] = $produto->domain;

            //seta o pid do produto
            $servicoVo->setPid($produto->pid);

            //vai buscar o gid do produto:
            $groupId = $servicoDao->grupoServico($servicoVo);

            //adiciona o group id ao array
            $newServico['gid'] = $groupId;

            // Append the new array to the $servico main array
            $servico[] = $newServico;
            unset($newServico);
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully that answers your question :)